# Fetch a session in PHP and send to browser to Circumvent CORS policy

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento

I was wondering if it would be possible to solve the following problem:

I'm working on a project where it links to a Magento cart at the last stage of a wizard, in order for the cart to recognise the items/session we have to do the following ajax request in the browser:

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     cache: false,
     global: false,
     timeout: 10000,
     url: 'http://thedomainame.co.uk/shop/groups/management/widget/',
     data: params2,
```

To be clear the flow is take input->validate->SEND AJAX for session->THEN do a post request with the item Id's - without fetching that management ajax first the cart doesn't recognise the session.

Now this is all well and good if it's just me(which it's not) and I can always deploy my code to the domainname.co.uk to test it, with numerous developers I need a way of fetching that session even on localhost.

Is there a way I can fetch that session in a local PHP script and then ajax that into the browser?

Thanks

Marc

Comment: Not totally clear where you want to get the session from? Is `http://thedomainame.co.uk` where all this is going on, or are you trying to get a session from another site you are not connected to

Comment: Ok our developers are normally working on localhost so I need them to be able to get the same session cookie in browser as they would if it was deployed to the right domain

Comment: All that ajax request does is grab the cookies from the magento shop so when the user navigates to the cart it recognises them.

Comment: so localhost->fetch session info from thedomain->checkout on thedomainname.co.uk